# How can I restricting grouping and draging inside a Kendo UI treeView

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I  got a KendoUI TreeView like this:

[image]

At the moment it is possible to switch the first level elements via drag and drop (group, rect-1.., line, text)
It should not be possible to group elements, drag elements from inside group outside a group.
it should be only possible to switch elements inside a group and switch elements on first level.

How can I do that?

Comment: Show us your code for generating the treeview.

Answer (score 0):

I trying to answer and i hope it meet the exact behavior that you want

> It should not be possible to group elements, drag elements from inside
>   group outside a group

- by this i'm guessing that you want the element/node can't change it's
  level (first if condition)

> it should be only possible to switch elements inside a group

- by this i'm guessing that you want only inside the 2nd element on
  each 1st element, cannot switch parent (first if condition)
- my (second if condition) doesn't allow you create 3rd element by
  dragging 2nd element over another 2nd element
- my (third if condition ) only allow moving 1st element , for now i comment it as i'm not sure what you mean by only allowing first element to change

Add drop function into your treeview, add this code :

```
drop: function(e) {
      var data = $('#treeview-left').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.sourceNode);
      var newData = $('#treeview-left').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.destinationNode);

      // do not allow changing levels
      if (data.parent() != newData.parent() ) {
         console.log("do not allow changing levels");
         e.setValid(false);
      }
      // do not allow adding to leaf node
      if (!newData.hasChidren && e.dropPosition == "over") {
         console.log("do not allow adding to leaf node");
         e.setValid(false);
      }

      //only allow 1st level element drag drop but not 2nd element
      //if (data.parent()){
      //   console.log("only allow 1st parent drag drop");
      //   e.setValid(false);
     // }

},
```

> [KENDO DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/idETU)